# FullCalendar - changeView not resetting onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to change the view of a calendar, and show a specific date range, based on some fields content.

The date format from inside these 2 fields are like this : 2018-05-05

Here's my code:

```
$('#checkRange').on('click', function () {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'list', {
        start: $('#firstDate').val(),
        end: $('#endDate').val()
      });
});
```

So basically, when I click on the "checkRange" button, I want the calendar to switch the view to the list view, and change the "start" and "end" options to the value inside the "firstDate" field, and "endDate" field.

It works fine the first time the page loads, but it looks like once the "start" and "end" options are set, even if I change the content of the "firstDate" and "endDate" fields, and click the "checkRange" button again, it will not update the view.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I have a really similar question currently up. If anyone replies I will let you know.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully someone will post an answer soon :)

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/rerenderEvents

```
$("selector").fullCalendar( ‘rerenderEvents’ );
```

or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/refetchEvents

```
$("selector").fullCalendar( ‘refetchEvents’ );
```